# Adding image as a label on edge in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

Created a graph using [cytoscape.js](http://js.cytoscape.org/). Need to add image as a label on edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After examination of

- `CanvasRenderer.drawElements` in https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/v2.3.8/src/extensions/renderer.canvas.drawing-redraw.js#L406-L412
- `CanvasRenderer.drawEdgeText` in https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/v2.3.8/src/extensions/renderer.canvas.drawing-label-text.js#L6-L31
- `CanvasRenderer.drawEdge` in https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/v2.3.8/src/extensions/renderer.canvas.drawing-edges.js

it **seems** that image label on edge is **not supported** right now.

One candidate where this feature might be added seems to be the `CanvasRenderer.drawEdgeText` function. The implementation might examine the text contained in the edge's `content` and if it looks like reference to an image (e.g. url) then draw it as image...

> https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/v2.3.8/README.md
>
> ### Contributing to Cytoscape.js
>
> Cytoscape.js is an open source project, and anyone interested is encouraged to contribute to Cytoscape.js.  We gladly accept pull requests.  If you are interested in regular contributions to Cytoscape.js, then we can arrange granting you permission to the repository by contacting us.
>
> If your pull request is a bugfix, please make changes to the master branch.  Otherwise, please make changes to the next version's branch (i.e. unstable).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer. but this will help somebody who looks for an answer as like me.
We can use icon fonts or fontawesome for this.
set the edges data as

```
edges = {
 data:
 id: "3f5cb5c4-43aa-4f4d-b816-fb4f279585c7"
 label: "1 A  \uf023 \uf022"  //this is the fontawesome unicode chars for lock and notes icons
 source: "1"
 sourceName: "shipping"
 target: "4"
 targetName: "twilio.com"
 value: 2
}
```

next in your cytoscape style, mention the font as fontawesome

```
{
      selector: '.autorotate',
      style: {
        'edge-text-rotation': 'autorotate',
        'font-size': '8px',
        // 'color': '#000000',
        'color': '#333333',
        'font-family': 'FontAwesome, helvetica neue Cantarell',
        'text-margin-x':'5px',
        'text-margin-y':'5px',
        // 'source-text-margin-x':'5px',
        // 'source-text-margin-y':'5px'
      }
    }
```

Now your cytoscape graph will show edges with images as like this
[image]

Comment: Does this work with font awesome 5? I tried this but it didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Yep, fontawesome in Label works, Refer [`Link`](http://jsfiddle.net/6ryp1wfa/)